# AngularFire2 / firestore valueChanges() returning null when there is data

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to get a document out of a firestore collection on load of a angularfire2 application. When loading the application in incognito mode the function returns null on first load, but after a refresh it returns the data I'm expecting.

```
public GetConfig(): Observable<Config> {
return this.documentDB
  .collection("Configs")
  .valueChanges()
  .do(c => {
    this.SetCurrentVersion((c[0] as Config).currentversion);
  })
  .map(c => c[0] as Config);
```

}

Has anyone else run into issues like this? I have verified that the Configs collection has documents available to be returned. My angularfire2 version is 5.0.0-rc.4.

I've also tried using snapshotChanges and getting the specific document from the collection, all are null on first load and work on refresh.

Comment: Did you get any solution on this?

Comment: What we ended up doing is checking the length of what was returned and throwing an error if it was 0. and adding .retry(3)  on the end of it. Not the best solution but it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up throwing an error if it didn't return us data and then retrying.

```
return this.documentDB
    .collection("Configs")
    .valueChanges()
    .do(c => {
      if (c.length > 0 && c != null) {
        this.config = c[0] as Config;
        this.SetCurrentVersion(this.config.currentversion);
      }
    })
    .map(c => {
      if (c.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("could not get config");
      } else {
        return c[0] as Config;
      }}).retry(5);
```